# Android:Receiving SMS from a specific number?

Tags: android, sms

I am new to android and I am working on an application in which I can set the phone number from whom I **receive** SMS and only that SMS will be acknowledged by the application. Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a code snippet -

```
public class SMSApp extends IntentReceiver {

static final String ACTION =
        "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

public void onReceiveIntent(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            SmsMessage[] messages = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
            for (int i = 0; i &lt; messages.length; i++) {
                SmsMessage message = messages[i];
                String phNum = message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                if ("xxx-xxx-xxxx".equals(phNum))
                {// Do your thing }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

You will of course need to put a receiver and a permission in the manifest similar to -

```
<uses-permission id="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<application>
    <receiver class="SMSApp">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:value="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: I am getting red line under IntentReceiver and also under Telephony in the second if statement. Its saying they both cannot be resolved to a type, can you please help me?

Comment: uses BroadcastReceiver, read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979540/how-can-i-intercept-an-incoming-sms-with-a-specific-text).

Comment: I have 2 sims in my phone! Is it possible to check which sim is receiving message?

Answer (score 1):

the above code is correct. to add on to it, remeber to add this.abortBroadcast() so that your default message app will not get the message from that particular number.for example:

```
    for (int i = 0; i &lt; messages.length; i++) {
            SmsMessage message = messages[i];
            String phNum = message.getOriginatingAddress();
            if (phNum.equals("000000")) {
               this.abortBroadcast();
               // do something
            } else {
               // do something else
            }

        }
```

Comment: Not possible since android 4.4. You cannot stop default messaging app to consume it.