# How can I intercept an incoming SMS message with specific text?

Tags: android

I want to know about intercepting an incoming SMS message for a specific key word; for example, "Hi", so that I can read that sms containing "Hi" in it and delete it after reading the message, and if that message doesn't contain any such text then it wouldn't be deleted and instead saved in the inbox.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Look for Broadcast Receiver, this is dependent on the apps installed on the phone but you can give your app priority for listening to messages. Although, when a notification is shown, the message won't be in the SMS Database yet, so you will need to use abortBroadcast() to stop other apps being notified. See example below:

```
public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
             Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
             SmsMessage messages =SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);    
             Log.i(TAG,  messages.getMessageBody());
                 if(messages.getMessageBody().contains("Hi")) {
                     abortBroadcast();
                 }
    }
```

And you would need to declare the receiver in the manifest, like so:

```
 <receiver android:name="com.encima.smsreceiver.MessageReceiver" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Finally, make sure you have the permission to RECEIVE_SMS in the manifest.

Comment: Using this method, the SMS does not get saved in the SMS inbox. How to save it in the SMS inbox as well?

Comment: @Siddharth To let the SMS continue, just ommit the abortBroadcast() line.

Comment: @Christoper Gwilliams The Google administrators for the Google Play Store consider the RECEIVE_SMS permission to be dangerous. As a result, an app that contains the permission will be rejected. Then the developer has to submit a form to Google Play administrators for approval. Other developers have mentioned the process is awful with feedback taking weeks, receiving only general feedback and often outright rejections are received with no explanations. Any ideas on how to avoid?

Answer (score 4):

### As of Android 4.4, what you ask to do in the question is impossible

Since Android version 4.4, If your app is not the default messaging app, you won't be able to perform those things promised in the accepted answer. You can neither stop the default messaging app from getting notified, nor you can delete an sms message.

Comment: I've cleared the comments and made an edit on the answer. If you disagree with my edit, feel free to roll it back. However, if you choose to do so, please make sure to make it clear how your answer answers the question as it was asked, without relying on the current accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks. It is fine. As long as people can see it fast, I am ok.