# Receiving SMS messages in my app

Tags: java, android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I am creating an app that receives SMS text messages, I have created a class that extends BroadcastReceiver to receive and display SMS messagesin a toast within the app. I have also added permissions too my manifest along with the declaration of the receiver. The problem is it still does not seem to display the message. It will only appear on the top bar as a notification. Hopefully someone will be able to see where i am going wrong. Do i have to have some code in my mainactivity in order to display the message?? or should it display in my all my activities straight from the receiver clas?? code below:

**UPDATE**
I ended up deleting my receiver and recreating everything, now it seems to work fine 
SmsReceiver.java:

```
 public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();


    if (extras ==null)
        return;
    //toast
    Toast.makeText(context, "Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");

    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
        SmsMessage SMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        String sender = SMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
        String body = SMessage.getMessageBody().toString();

        Intent in = new Intent("SmsMessage.intent.MAIN").putExtra("get_msg", sender+":"+body);

        context.sendBroadcast(in);
        this.abortBroadcast();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: A toast can generally not be shown from a BroadcastReceiver (unless it's part of a process which also happens to have a visible activity). Use a notification instead.

Comment: so would it be possible to put the message into a global variable to then be displayed on my main activity??

Comment: I have an sms app - you can show toast from BroadcastReceiver. This is not a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is it still does not seem to display the message. It will only appear on the top bar as a notification

do you know what is - [Ordered Broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendOrderedBroadcast%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.String%29)?

in case you don't know - it's a broadcast that receives synchronously (one after another) by all receivers that registered for this broadcast.  you can set in the manifest receiver deceleration a [priority](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html#priority)  , and each one of the receivers can control if the broadcast will pass on in the priorities chain to additional registered receivers by using the [aboartBroadcast()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#abortBroadcast%28%29) method.

what's to this and receiving SMS? - the system sends ordered broadcast when SMS receives.  if your receivers priority is lower then the "default SMS app" priority - then what usually happens is that the application that got the broadcast first will cancel the broadcast, and you'll never receives it.

to get the broadcast before the default SMS application you have to declare your receiver with high priority (providing priority = 1000 should do the trick).

without providing priority - it's automatically set to zero.

you can have a look on this example - [How Can i INTERCEPT an Incoming SMS With A specific Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979540/how-can-i-intercept-an-incoming-sms-with-a-specific-text)

also make sure you declared the permission to RECEIVE_SMS in the manifest

Comment: ah i see so adding this should make it work??
      <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                    <action     android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

Comment: yes, and you have also to abort the broadcast in the end of onHandleIntent() method.  make sure also that the SMSReceiver class is in the java files root package name of your application. that's how you declared in in the manifest..

Comment: Oh, i thought you have intent-filter in your manifest. Next time read Android Documentation to prevent such questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979540/how-can-i-intercept-an-incoming-sms-with-a-specific-text

Comment: hmm still not working for some reason. Still displays message notification on the top bar but no toast

Comment: @CBandroidDev: it should work if you did everything as I explained. have you seen the page I linked you to above?  did you canceled the broadcast? did you debug with break points the receiver when SMS receives?

Comment: I know, thats why i can't seem to get my head round it :s the way its coded looks like it should work :s i've included permissions in my manifest along with priority.

Comment: show me your current receiver code, and manifest receiver deleration

Comment: Could it possibly be the location ive placed my receiver declaration in the manifest?? does it have to be inside an activity?

Comment: @CBandroidDev: hhh..  you aborted the broadcast inside the for(i..) loop.  you should abort the broadcast !!!in the last code line of the receiver!!!

Comment: @CBandroidDev: the receiver should !!not!! be inside activity.  int the java receiver code I don't see the first line - package name declaration. I need to see if it's the same package deceleration as your app package name

Comment: @TalKanel the receiver is declared within <application> not <activity> also I have made sure i have included the package declaration and it is all the same

Comment: @CBandroidDev: it should work.  have a look also on this tutorial - http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/227-handle-sms-on-android  . besides that I really can't do anything remotely (and I guess no one could..).  maybe you have another application that receives SMS with higher priority the 1000. try higher priority...

Comment: @TalKanel thank you very much for your help, it does seem strange that it doesn't work, just can't get my head around it at all. i'll give higher priority a go

Comment: maybe i should just start again fresh using the tutorial you just posted

Comment: @CBandroidDev: have you tried putting the abortBroadcast() method outside the "for(i)" loop as I suggested? it suppose to be the last code line in the receiver. not inside loop

Comment: @TalKanel I have yes, still nothing, still only appearing on the top bar which i thought the abortBroadcast would stop

Comment: Could it possibly have something to do with the android minimum version i have set it to in my manifest??

Comment: @TalKanel not entirely sure why but after giving up with this yesterday, i've now reopened eclipse today and it works! slightly confused but i'm glad its working. I have noticed though that if i comment out the toast message, it will still appear, its like there's something not right between my computer and the app on the phone :s

Comment: @CBandroidDev: Glad to here that.   don't forget to upvote + remark my answer as currect :->    I'm sure that without setting priority to the receiver - it would not work anyway...

Comment: @CBandroidDev: pretty sad you decided give your accept answer to someone wrote you some code without any explanations (I don't even understand what he showed you that you did not knew already, besides removing all the "buggy" parts from your own receiver..) .  after all - understanding ordered broadcast as I explained is the important part

Comment: @TalKanel Sorry, you're right, I have changed it back to you. Thanks again for all your help :)

Comment: @Tal Kanel The Google administrators for the Google Play Store consider the RECEIVE_SMS permission (in the tutorial you mention) to be dangerous. As a result, an app that contains the permission will be rejected. Then the developer has to submit a form to Google Play administrators for approval. Other developers have mentioned the process is awful with feedback taking weeks and receiving outright rejections with either no explanations or generic feedback. Any ideas on how to avoid?

Answer (score 1):

Try starting again and setting up your receiver like so....

```
 public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();


    if (extras ==null)
        return;
    //toast
    Toast.makeText(context, "Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");

    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
        SmsMessage SMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        String sender = SMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
        String body = SMessage.getMessageBody().toString();

        Intent in = new Intent("SmsMessage.intent.MAIN").putExtra("get_msg", sender+":"+body);

        context.sendBroadcast(in);
        this.abortBroadcast();

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        SmsMessage msgs[] = getMessagesFromIntent(arg1);
        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
               SmsMessage mesg = msgs[i];
               Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, mesg.getDisplayMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
               toast.show();
        }
}
```

Comment: still won't seem to display :s do i need code on my mainactivity to grab the message from the receiver or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
  SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
  String str = "";
  // retrieve the SMS message received ::
  Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
  msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
    str += "SMS from : " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
        str += " :";
        str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
        str += "\n";
   // Toast to display SMS ::
   Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   // Send SMS ::
   SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
   sms.sendTextMessage("put your phoneNumber(emulatorPort)", null, str, null, null);

    }
}
}
```

--
Have nice time !
Don't forget to add permissions !