# How to read the particular message format in android and store in sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

Am developing an GPS tracking android application, I get the GPS coordinates from the client side as sms. In server side i need to store the incoming sms in database. In my application i'm getting all the incoming messages to database, but i need to store only the particular message format in database. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

message format:

```
Lat:12.5678994
Lan:77.7847599
Accry:4.0
```

The above is the message format which am getting from client, i need to store only this in database, not all the incoming messages.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class SecureMessagesActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setTheme( android.R.style.Theme_Light );
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.findViewById( R.id.UpdateList ).setOnClickListener( this );
    }

    ArrayList<String> smsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id ) 
    {
        try 
        {
            //Retriving Lat Lan from msg body
                String[] splitted = smsList.get( pos ).split("\n"); 
            String sender = splitted[0];

            String data= splitted[2];
            String[] latval=data.split(":");
            String lat=latval[1];//Lat Value 

            String data1 = splitted[3];
            String[] lanval=data1.split(":");
            String lan=lanval[1];//Lan Value

            Toast.makeText( this, lat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            Toast.makeText( this, lan, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onClick( View v ) 
    {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query( Uri.parse( "content://sms/inbox" ), null, null, null, null);
        //Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),new String[]{phoneLookUp.DISPLAY_NAME}, condition, null, null, null);

        int indexBody = cursor.getColumnIndex( SmsReceiver.BODY );
        int indexAddr = cursor.getColumnIndex( SmsReceiver.ADDRESS );
        //int indexDate = cursor.getColumnIndex( SmsReceiver.DATE );

        if ( indexBody < 0 || !cursor.moveToFirst() ) return;

        smsList.clear();

        do
        {
            String str = getContactName(getApplicationContext(),cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SmsReceiver.ADDRESS)))+":"
                    + cursor.getString( indexAddr ) + "\n" 
                    + cursor.getString( indexBody );
            smsList.add( str );
        }
        while( cursor.moveToNext() );


        ListView smsListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.SMSList );
        smsListView.setAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsList) );
        smsListView.setOnItemClickListener( this );
    }

    public String getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri,
                new String[] { PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String contactName = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            contactName = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return contactName;
    }

}
```

SMSReceiver.java:

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

```
public static final String SMS_EXTRA_NAME = "pdus";
public static final String SMS_URI = "content://sms";

public static final String ADDRESS = "address";
public static final String PERSON = "person";
public static final String DATE = "date";
public static final String READ = "read";
public static final String STATUS = "status";
public static final String TYPE = "type";
public static final String BODY = "body";
public static final String SEEN = "seen";

public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX = 1;
public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT = 2;

public static final int MESSAGE_IS_NOT_READ = 0;
public static final int MESSAGE_IS_READ = 1;

public static final int MESSAGE_IS_NOT_SEEN = 0;
public static final int MESSAGE_IS_SEEN = 1;

// Change the password here or give a user possibility to change it
```

// public static final byte[] PASSWORD = new byte[]{ 0x20, 0x32, 0x34, 0x47, (byte) 0x84, 0x33, 0x58 };

```
public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) 
{
    // Get SMS map from Intent
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    String messages = "";

    if ( extras != null )
    {
        // Get received SMS array
        Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get( SMS_EXTRA_NAME );

        // Get ContentResolver object for pushing encrypted SMS to incoming folder
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

       // for ( int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i )
        //{
            SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[0]);

            String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
            if(sms.getMessageBody().contains("Lat:"))
            {
            String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
            messages += "SMS from " + address + " :\n";                    
            messages += sms.getMessageBody().toString() + "\n";
            putSmsToDatabase( contentResolver, sms );
            Toast.makeText( context, messages, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            this.abortBroadcast();              }
        //}

        // Display SMS message
        //Toast.makeText( context, messages, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }

    // WARNING!!! 
    // If you uncomment next line then received SMS will not be put to incoming.
    // Be careful!

}

private void putSmsToDatabase( ContentResolver contentResolver, SmsMessage sms )
{
    // Create SMS row
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put( ADDRESS, sms.getOriginatingAddress() );
    values.put( DATE, sms.getTimestampMillis() );
    values.put( READ, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_READ );
    values.put( STATUS, sms.getStatus() );
   // values.put( TYPE, MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX );
    values.put( SEEN, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_SEEN );
    try
    {
        String encryptedPassword= sms.getMessageBody().toString();


        //String encryptedPassword = StringCryptor.encrypt( new String(PASSWORD), sms.getMessageBody().toString() ); 
        values.put( BODY, encryptedPassword );


    }
    catch ( Exception e ) 
    { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

    // Push row into the SMS table
    contentResolver.insert( Uri.parse( SMS_URI ), values );
}
```

}

Comment: see the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979540/how-can-i-intercept-an-incoming-sms-with-a-specific-text)

Comment: Are you sure your `onReceive()` is being called??? Add a Toast or Log inside `onReceive()` and check..

Comment: ya onreceive is been called..but it again showing all the messages

Comment: can you post your new `SMSReceiver.java` @user3551248

Comment: Where you have written the `if` condition in my answer.. Please write that in onReceive() @user3551248

Comment: for ( int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i )
            {
             SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);
             
             String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
             if(sms.getMessageBody().contains("Lat:")) {
             String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
                messages += "SMS from " + address + " :\n";                    
                messages += body + "\n";
                putSmsToDatabase( contentResolver, sms );
                //abortBroadcast();
             }
            }

Comment: replace `messages += body + "\n";` to `messages += sms.getMessageBody().toString() + "\n";` and check..

Comment: for ( int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i )
            {
             SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);
             
             String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
             if(sms.getMessageBody().contains("Lat:")) {
             String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
                messages += "SMS from " + address + " :\n";                    
                messages += sms.getMessageBody().toString() + "\n";
                putSmsToDatabase( contentResolver, sms );

Comment: Now what happened after this code??? @user3551248

Comment: its showing all the sms...

Comment: What message did you send??? Did it contains "Lat:" as message body???

Comment: ya it contains Lat as message body... but it is showing other message that do not contain "Lat:"

Comment: showing means???? where are the messages shown??? in the database??

Comment: Are you sure `putSmsToDatabase( contentResolver, sms ); ` is inside the `if` loop ????

Comment: It is fetching all the new incoming message from inbox..

Comment: yes it will...but only the messages that contain "Lat:" will be stored in the database.. That's what the code is..

Comment: if(sms.getMessageBody().contains("Lat:"))
             {
             String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
                messages += "SMS from " + address + " :\n";                    
                messages += sms.getMessageBody().toString() + "\n";
                putSmsToDatabase( contentResolver, sms );
                //abortBroadcast();
             }

Comment: ya it is in if loop itself..

Comment: Change "Lat:" to "#####" in your code and try sending that as sms and see..

Comment: k k.. but i need to display only messages that contains Lat:12.5678994
Lan:77.7847599
Accry:4.0.... I don need to display other messages in list... wat i have to do??

Comment: could you please do one thing...edit your question and add new updated SMSReceiver.java please..

Comment: I think its correct..only thing is Move `Toast.makeText( context, messages, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();` and `abortBroadcast();` to inside of `if` loop..

Comment: Again it is displaying the messages that do not have the format..Lat:12.5678994 Lan:77.7847599 Accry:4.0. wat to do??

Comment: You sure that the message which was sent didnt have "#####" in it???

Comment: i want only to view the message format which i mentioned above in my update list not all the incoming sms formats

Comment: ya tried it but again it displaying all the inbox messages

Comment: That means your `if(sms.getMessageBody().contains("#####"))` always returning true???

Comment: ya.. wat is the else statement??

Comment: remove the for loop and try...Actually what is the need of that for loop??

Comment: ya removed but getting error in this line...SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);
I have used "i" in that for loop..

Comment: give `smsExtra[0]` @user3551248

Comment: No... It is not working....

Comment: What happened???Any error???

Comment: Again same problem... displaying all the messages from inbox..

Comment: Where does it display?? You mean it gets inserted in database???

Comment: post your updated SMSReceiver.java code as question please

Comment: ya.. it should be inserted into the database... I have put one buuton in my main avtivity.. when ever i click that button i need to display only the messages containing the above message format..

Comment: see my mainActivity.java.. in that i have one button UpdateSmsList.. if click that button i want to display the messages containing "Lat"

Comment: That is you want to save all those messages in the format to be saved in the database and then retrieve from database on buttonclick..right??

Comment: ok...So check the latest value that is inserted in the database..

Comment: What i need to do for that???

Comment: I din get u.. How can i check the latest value??

Comment: you can see the database values in adt..go to DDMS--> file explorer-->data--> data--> your package name-->databases

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321246/how-can-i-read-my-database-from-ddms)

Comment: k k... am checking wait..

Comment: Inside the database.. I have 2 files...1.sms.db   2.sms.db-journal these 2 files r seeing but i cant open n see the latest values

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321246/how-can-i-read-my-database-from-ddms) to pull the database... You'll have to pull the database to see data in it,..

Comment: I saw that... but not getting anything

Comment: how can i pull that database

Comment: what is happening when u pull it???

Comment: once you select your database, you will see two icons on the upper right tab wherein you can push or pull the database

Comment: 2 files are seeing.... sms.db and sms.db-journal

Comment: select sms.db .. Ithink thats your database..

Comment: ya i have pulled my database

Comment: now check the values in it..

Comment: how can i open that one?.. it is in notepad format... not showing anything..

Comment: is there any file extensions to it??

Comment: How can i extract db file?? How can i see the values in it??

Comment: Download SQLiteManager from this [link](http://sqlitemanager.en.softonic.com/)

Comment: now open the db in that..

Comment: No am not gteting anything in that..

Comment: So that means nothing is getting inserted in the database..So my answer is correct..Kindly mark my answer as accepted please..I'l continue my support..

Comment: How an i insert the values in database

Comment: How an i insert the values in database?? Plz help me now

Comment: See this [link](http://pankajkakade101.wordpress.com/2013/04/11/read-each-new-incoming-sms-massages-in-android-and-put-it-into-database-using-service/) for that.. @user3551248

Comment: Thanks am getting the messages in database, now will u please help me to view on the message format which i mentioned above in list view

Comment: My code is such that only sms in that format will only be inserted into the database..and later in click event fetch those database values directly..

Comment: please send me that code

Comment: The above code works just like that..only thing is that write database insertion as a function and call it in place of `putSmsToDatabase`..Then the code will become correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
if(messages.getMessageBody().contains("Lat:")) {

     //Write your database insertion code here

}
```

or

I have one solution for that..May not be the correct one..But still..
Try sending the sms with a special header ie for eg "#####" and check for the "#####" like this..

```
if(messages.getMessageBody().contains("#####")) {

      //Write your database insertion code here

}
```

Comment: ya checked onReceive is been called

Comment: can you please post your new SMSReceiver.java @user3551248

Comment: i postted both the java files, smsREcevier.java and mainActivity

Comment: But i cant see the `if` condition in your `SMSReceiver.java`..Check if it is the updated one..

Comment: for ( int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i ) { SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]); String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString(); if(sms.getMessageBody().contains("Lat:")) { String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress(); messages += "SMS from " + address + " :\n"; messages += body + "\n"; putSmsToDatabase( contentResolver, sms ); //abortBroadcast(); } }

Comment: Show me the exact message content which you sent... @user3551248

Comment: Lat:12.5678994
Lan:77.7847599
Accry:4.0

Comment: Thats correct naa... If message body contains "Lat:" then it will enter the `if` loop ..So the code is correct..

Comment: But i don need to store messages thah do not contain Lat:12.5678994 Lan:77.7847599 Accry:4.0