# Receive specific SMS and elaborate it with an Android app?

Tags: android, bluetooth, sms, android-bluetooth

sorry fo my complete ignorance developing an Android.
I'm asking about the feaseability of this pseudocode I would like to implement as native app; let imagine a task that:

```
when a specific SMS arrive (only those sent from a specific sender number)
possibly (multi-SMS in case of text bigger than 160 chars )
elaborate/format each received SMS:
    . save text content on a local db
    . print text on a bluetooth printer
    . reply to sender with some sort of "ACK" SMS
```

BTW, what above could be sort of background task, and I would need on foreground a sort of user interface that visualizes received SMS and do some user actions (sending back SMS to sender)

Is all that possible on Android ? Any issue ?

I mean, above all: is possible to "catch" specific SMSs (by example those sent by a specific sender number), living unalterated the usual SMS workflow for ALL other SMSs ?

Sorry for my beginner question and Thanks for your patience
giorgio

www.giorgiorobino.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [this link](http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87) to implement a `BroadcastReceiver` that will listen for incoming SMS.

Inside your onReceive from your `BroadcastReceiver`, handle your logic (print/save/..)

Comment: thanks @DroidBender, for the specific example. Showing to user a message box (that disappear after few seconds) would be superb. Question: when intercepting certain SMS with `BroadcastReceiver` mean that the received SMS will be still VISIBLE to the user SMS queue / Android standard SMS management app ?

Comment: Yes, they are stored in the Android system itself (an SQL db). Client application simply use this database.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, yes. But not recommended. That being said the way to set this up is to catch the SMS intent, so your app would be started when an SMS is received. Otherwise it would not run at all (as long as you don't have any other interface open). For a code example on the message interception part, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979540/how-can-i-intercept-an-incoming-sms-with-a-specific-text) post. For the database part look up local storage on android phones. Look up on SMS messaging for the reply. Not sure how bluetooth printing would work as I've never done it, but if it's a standard protocol I'm sure there's either built in support or a library for it.

Comment: thanks. yes I woukd like to intercept&process just incoming SMSs sent from a specific number (let say +393930000001), leaving all other incoming SMS to standard / default Andorid processing. That's not reccomended ?

Comment: @Solyaris Well, as long as you know what you're doing there's nothing inherently wrong with it. Problem is if you don't and end up blocking SMS messages from your users as they are processed in your app. If you do this and intend to distribute it, make absolutely sure that ONLY the messages from the right number is intercepted.

Comment: Yes, I understand the possible "collateral effects"